# Android how to use background service to trigger screen rotation

Tags: android, orientation

I have a tablet and also I have some test cases want to do.

By triggering screen rotation, I know setRequestedOrientation is a workable api.

However, will it be possible to do it in background service?

Say, can I run the service and look at my home screen to rotate every 1 second?

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Why do you need a button to do setrequested orientation?

You can just do         `this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); `

Comment: `setRequestedOrientation` can be used to request a certain orientation for your app, not for other apps like the home screen. > No luck in a background service.

Comment: thanks but i am looking for the answer which teaches me how to do the screen rotation in the home screen. not for other apps.

Comment: @Sam - The home screen is just an system app.